# On what parameters does the Event Horizon depend on?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

In the Schwarzschild metric, I know it depends only on mass.

But in rotational black holes, it also depends on the angular momentum.

I know hawking radiation can decrease the mass of the black hole, reducing its mass, and feeding and merging black holes can increase their size by increasing their mass.

Answer (score 1):

All properties of steady-state black holes, including the location of their event horizon, depend on only *three* parameters: their mass, their charge, and their angular momentum.

This is the famous [no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).

Comment: So, for example, we should not be able to find a black hole with low mass and great radius, right?

Comment: Right, we should not.